# Why am I getting connection timed out when connecting to AWS Document DB from my local machine with TLS disabled?

Tags: aws-documentdb

When utilizing AWS' connection string to connect to my Amazon Document DB instance in Robo3T I'm getting a 'Connection Timed Out' error.

`Error connecting to ....cluster-....us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 (123.45.67.89:27017) :: caused by :: Connection timed out :`

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not currently support connecting to Document DB from public endpoints when not using SSH.

> Connecting from Public Endpoints
>
> You are trying to connect to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster directly
> from your laptop or local development machine.
>
> Trying to connect to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster directly from a
> public endpoint, such as your laptop or local development machine,
> will fail. Amazon DocumentDB is virtual private cloud (VPC)-only and
> does not currently support public endpoints. Thus, you can't connect
> directly to your Amazon DocumentDB cluster from your laptop or local
> development environment outside of your VPC.
>
> To connect to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster from outside an Amazon VPC,
> you can use an SSH tunnel. For more information, see Connecting to an
> Amazon DocumentDB Cluster from Outside an Amazon VPC. Additionally, if
> your development environment is in a different Amazon VPC, you can
> also use VPC Peering and connect to your Amazon DocumentDB cluster
> from another Amazon VPC in the same region or a different region.

More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.connecting.html#troubleshooting.cannot-connect.public-endpoints

Comment: +1, for Robo3T i recommend using SSH tunnel. Here is a blog with some instructions https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-3-getting-started-with-amazon-documentdb-using-robo-3t/

Comment: Honestly I don't have the patience for DocumentDB. I think MongoDB Atlas is far more mature, robust, and feature rich as a cloud Mongo provider. I wouldn't waste any personal or professional time with DocumentDB.